# How to get list of logrotate files

Tags: logrotate

How can my program iterate through the log history created by `logrotate`?

`logrotate` has many options for file naming. For example, `dateext`, `delaycompress`, and `rotate` all affect the filenames in some way. I want my program to be Linux-friendly and work with most of these options.

I read the entire manpage of `logrotate`, and did not find any description of how other software can inspect the files that `logrotate` has produced. Is there perhaps some sister utility that understands what `logrotate` has done to my logfiles, and can make it easy to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rereading the manpage 3 more times, I found the following words:

> Note that the datestamps generated  by this format must be lexically sortable ...
>   when using the rotate option, logrotate sorts all rotated filenames to find out which logfiles are older

So we have a *documented* method for finding the files.
For reverse chronological order, the sorting must be reversed when `dateext` is used, of course.